# Where to place common utility methods on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

In Visual Studio projects I almost always use the **App_Code folder** or a reference to a  separate class library to store my most commonly used Methods, like a  method that formats dates.

**Where and how should I do the same when developing an iPhone App using Xcode?**

Is this best practice when it comes to iPhone Apps?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about common code you want to share between projects, right?

There are a few ways to handle this. Building your own Framework is one possibility, you can see this in action in [OmniGroup's open source framework](http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/). In my opinion though, building a framework can be pretty cumbersome. I prefer to simply keep a directory of source files that I can reference (not copy) from each project I'm using them in. I don't even do that much anymore in my Cocoa projects though, it seems like most of the truly portable code that I have a use for in multiple projects has been included in successive releases of Cocoa.

Comment: Building your own framework is almost always a bad idea. YAGNI.